# Leaflet: showing dynamic polylines together on a map using layers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm working on a task of showing all polylines(of different colours) on my map using leaflet. I'm getting all my dynamic polylines' latitudes and longitudes with their colours but when I merge it using layers, it just takes the last polyline and shows it.

I think I'm making some mistake in layering it. Can someone recommend the correct way to layer polylines in leaflets?

Here's a sample of the code where this is happening -

```
      let newColour = this.returnMapColor(moment(startDate).day());
      
      var layerGroups = {}
      console.log("colour", newColour, startDate );
      let range = this.props.history.filter((v) => { return moment(v.time).format("YYYY-MM-DD")  == moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD") });
      startDate = moment(startDate).add(1, 'days');

      range.map((row)=> {
        positions.push([row.latitude,row.longitude,row.sp] )
      });

      if(this.props.map){
        const leafletMap = this.props.map.leafletElement;   

         this.hotlineLayer = L.layerGroup(L.polyline(positions, {color: newColour})).addTo(leafletMap);

      } 
      ++i;
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure because I couldn't reach full scope of your code. But as far as I understand, you're pushing the point coordinates into an array which keeps the point positions and passing that array to layer group instance once. You should set the all coordinates of lines and pass the array of lines of coordinates to L.polyline(...).
And lastly please have a look at [Polyline -> Usage Example](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polyline)
Then I think you will notice what you did and should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polyline requires at least two sets of `lat, longs`. Could you point out where in your code are you forming `polylines`?

In your code, the `range.map` the operation will only lead to creating an array of positions. And hence, your code is rendering a single line.

If you intend to create multiple polylines and render them using `LayerGroup`, I would suggest something in the lines of:

```
var latlngs1 = [
     [45.51, -122.68,0],
     [37.77, -122.43,1],
     [34.04, -118.2,2]
];

var latlngs2 = [
     [34.04, -118.2,2],
     [32.08, -110.5,2]
];

const polyline1 = L.polyline(latlngs1, {color: 'red'})

var polyline2 = L.polyline(latlngs2, {color: 'blue'})

var hotlineLayer = L.layerGroup([polyline1, polyline2]).addTo(map);
```

Example Code: https://jsfiddle.net/idhruvs/n75omjbd/32/

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm getting my lat longs from backend which are I the correct format. The problem with using polyline1 and so on is that polyline is dynamic. How do I combine all dynamic polylines in L.layerGroup? The value of that I'm getting is        latitude: 13.3007316
longitude: 76.52755 and so on